# Where to find census data for many countries?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, census

I'm working on a GIS project and could really use your help. I've been googling all day but haven't had any luck. Where can I find:

- list of all countries with reputable census data and link to the data
- list all the statistical boundaries per country with census data

Answer (score 1):

By no means comprehensive, but [RT Wilson's free GIS data list](https://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/) is a good place to start. Scroll down to the `Individual Country/Area Datasets` section and search for "census."

- [Australian Government Data](http://data.gov.au/data/?format=Shapefile): Data from the Australian Government's OpenData programme, including soil, climate and census data. This link shows only data available as shapefiles. Click the KML link to show KML data instead.
- [China Dimensions Data Collection](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/collection/cddc): GIS data including administrative regions, census data linked to maps and agricultural data.
- [Diamond Bay Data](http://www.dbr.nu/data/geo/): Chinese counties, census statistics and Digital Chart of the World China GIS layers.
- [Irish Census Boundaries 2006](http://census.cso.ie/censusasp/saps/boundaries/census2006_boundaries.htm): Census boundaries from the Irish census in 2006, in shapefile format.
- [Great Britain Historical Database Online](http://hds.essex.ac.uk/history/data/access.asp): Historical statistics linked to spatial areas including census data, births/marriages/deaths statistics and many others
- [United Kingdom ONS Geoportal](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page): Downloadable data from the Office for National Statistics, including census data, administrative boundaries, postcode locations etc.
- [United Kingdom Census boundary data](http://census.ukdataservice.ac.uk/get-data/boundary-data.aspx): Boundaries for census data areas, for both current and historical censuses
- [TIGER](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/): US-wide census data.
- [TIGER/Line 2010](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html): 2010 extracts from the census database. These files contain the boundaries of census areas, which can then be linked to census data tables.

Now you have data for 7 out of 206 sovereign nations in the world.